# Is TestNG's ITestResult Interface or a Class? if interface which class implemented this interface?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, testng

Is TestNG's "ITestResult" an Interface or a Class? we are using the below code to take the screenshot of the webpage whenever there is a failure. we are getting the status of the test by using ITestResult. I have checked the TestNG's API and it is showing as ITestResult as a interface, then which class is implemented this interface? And how we are accessing the method getStatus() using Interface reference? Can anyone clarify my doubt?

```
@AfterMethod(alwaysRun=true)
public void takeScreenShot(ITestResult result){
    if(result.getStatus()==2){
        ITestNGMethod instance = result.getMethod();
        String testName = instance.getMethodName();
        TestUtil.captureScreen("xyz", testName,"Failure_Screenshots");--> method to take screen shot and save the image file in specific directory
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: What are the import statements in the class that has this method? Have you tried running this in debug mode with a breakpoint that will allow you to step into the code as it executes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[org.testng.internal.TestResult](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.testng/testng/6.8.8/org/testng/internal/TestResult.java?av=f) is the class which implements the ITestResult interface.
In eclipse, you can click on a type and click Ctrl+T to see the Type Hierarchy to get this data for any type.